# Denormalize list in a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this (from mongo db..)

```
team_id <- c(1,2)
member <- c("15,25,35","12,22,32")
data.frame (team_id,member)
```

which I'm trying to convert data frame like this..

```
team_id2 <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
member2 <- c(15,25,35,12,22,32)
data.frame (team_id2, member2)
```

I tried to use 'unlist' but cannot get "team_id" to be repeated every column. I will appreciate any guidance on this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `cSplit` from `library(splitstackshape)`.  It is easy and compact to work with `cSplit` for these kind of problems.  We just provide the column to split i.e. `member`, the delimiter (`,`) and the direction (`long`).

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(d1, "member", sep=",", "long")
#    team_id member
#1:       1     15
#2:       1     25
#3:       1     35
#4:       2     12
#5:       2     22
#6:       2     32
```

---

or using `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(d1)`), grouped by 'team_id', we split the 'member' by `,` and `unlist` the output.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d1)[, .(member=unlist(tstrsplit(member, ","))), team_id]
#   team_id member
#1:       1     15
#2:       1     25
#3:       1     35
#4:       2     12
#5:       2     22
#6:       2     32
```

---

Or using `tidyr`, we can split the 'member' by `,` and `unnest` (from `tidyr`)

```
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
unnest(d1[1], member= str_split(d1$member, ","))
#Source: local data frame [6 x 2]

#  team_id member
#   (dbl)  (chr)
#1       1     15
#2       1     25
#3       1     35
#4       2     12
#5       2     22
#6       2     32
```

---

Or we can use a `base R` solution.  We use `strsplit` to `split` the 'member' column into a `list`, set the `names` of the `list` as 'team_id' and use `stack` to convert the `list` to `data.frame`

```
stack(setNames(strsplit(as.character(d1$member), ","), d1$team_id))[2:1]
```

#### data

```
d1 <- data.frame (team_id,member)
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a base R solution:

```
ms <- strsplit(as.character(df$member),',');
df2 <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)),sapply(ms,length)),];
df2$member <- unlist(ms);
df2;
##     team_id member
## 1         1     15
## 1.1       1     25
## 1.2       1     35
## 2         2     12
## 2.1       2     22
## 2.2       2     32
```

You can replace `sapply(ms,length)` with [`lengths(ms)`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lengths.html) if you're using a recent enough version of R.

Answer (score 2):

To throw in a `tidyr` solution:

```
library(tidyr)
team_id <- c(1,2)
member <- c("15,25,35","12,22,32")
old <- data.frame (team_id, member, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

## need to determine how many items there are at most in column 'member'
maxItems <- max(sapply(strsplit(old$member, ","), length))

old %>% separate(member, seq_len(maxItems), ",") %>% 
        gather(position, member, -team_id) 
#   team_id position member
# 1       1        1     15
# 2       2        1     12
# 3       1        2     25
# 4       2        2     22
# 5       1        3     35
# 6       2        3     32
```