# convert data frame with a column of type list to a flat data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe, casting

I have a data frame where one of the columns is a list. I would like to cast it into a whole data frame:

```
df=data.frame(col1=c(LETTERS[1:3]),col2=c('X,Y,Z','W,V','U'))
> df
  col1  col2
1    A X,Y,Z
2    B   W,V
3    C     U
>
```

And want to make another dataframe for ease of viewing and further processing such as:

```
> data.frame(col1=c('A','A','A','B','B','C'),col2=LETTERS[26:21])
  col1 col2
1    A    Z
2    A    Y
3    A    X
4    B    W
5    B    V
6    C    U
>
```

The number of values in col2 vary from 1 to 5 in my real data set. Currently I have tried

```
library(stringr)
> str_split(df[,2],',')
[[1]]
[1] "X" "Y" "Z"

[[2]]
[1] "W" "V"

[[3]]
[1] "U"
```

and

```
> unlist(str_split(df[,2],','))
[1] "X" "Y" "Z" "W" "V" "U"
```

But am not sure how to proceed to link each col2 value with its correct col1 value

Answer (score -1):

We can do this with `base R`

```
 stack(setNames(strsplit(as.character(df$col2), ","), df$col1))
```

Comment: Why don't you provide it to the dupe target?

Comment: Or add a link to a similar answer of yours (http://stackoverflow.com/a/37130811/3521006)